# Polymer property not working if not in tag

Tags: javascript, html, polymer

I'm trying to lean `Polymer` and I'm looking at [this tutorial](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/start/quick-tour.html).

The problem that i'm experiencing is a the [Declary a property](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/start/quick-tour.html#declare-a-property) section, if i don't put the template `{{owner}}` in a `span` or `b` it doesn't get interpreted.
So my question is basically if this works

```
This is <b>{{owner}}</b>'s configurable-name-tag element.
```

Why doesn't this ?

```
This is {{owner}}'s configurable-name-tag element
```

Notice the missing `<b>`.

[Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/6a8E6t10JnwWdZF9KEOa?p=preview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because Polymer v1, unlike v0.5, doesn't support string concatenation.

The binding annotation must currently span the entire content of the tag, as you can read on the official documentation: https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding.html#binding-to-text-content